# ActiveMQ Artemis unable to establish connection to Spring Boot Client

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, activemq-artemis

I have ActiveMQ Artemis 2.8.1 running and get the following error when I try to connect to it using a Spring Boot application over SSL.

```
ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224018: Failed to create session: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
Line 11: expected [{], found [sufficient]
```

Additionally, I get this line in the logs that I've never seen before.

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221053: Disallowing use of vulnerable protocol 'SSLv2Hello' on acceptor 'netty-ssl-acceptor'. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/poodlecve-2014-3566-2339408.html for more details.
```

I had ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18.0 running initially, and then changed `ARTEMIS_HOME` in `artemis.profile` to point to the directory containing 2.8.1 for compatibility reasons. I'm wondering if that change has anything to do with this.
How do I go about resolving this issue?

`broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
    KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
    -->

    <configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 125 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 8000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>8000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->

      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->

         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

     <!-- SSL Acceptor -->
     <acceptor name="netty-ssl-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;verifyHost=false;anycastPrefix=jms.queue;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/opt/sprink-broker/etc/oceanBroker.jks;keyStorePassword=changeit;trustStorePath=/opt/sprink-broker/etc/oceanBroker.ts;trustStorePassword=changeit;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE</acceptor>

     <acceptor name="mqtt-ssl-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:8883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;anycastPrefix=jms.queue;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/opt/sprink-broker/etc/oceanBroker.jks;keyStorePassword=changeit;trustStorePath=/opt/sprink-broker/etc/oceanBroker.ts;trustStorePassword=changeit;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq, users"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq, users"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq, users"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq, users"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq, users"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq, users"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq, users"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq, users"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq, users"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>


      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

   </core>
</configuration>
```

Spring Boot config file used to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis:

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.JMSException;


@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MQTTConfig {

    @Value("${activemq.broker-url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${activemq.ssl-url}")
    private String sslUrl;

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_TRUSTSTORE}")
    private String pathToTrustStore;

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_KEYSTORE}")
    private String pathToKeystore;

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}")
    private String truststorePassword;

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}")
    private String keystorePassword;

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisSSLConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://ip:port?&" + "sslEnabled=true&" +
                "trustStorePath=" + pathToTrustStore + "&trustStorePassword=xxxxx");
        artemisConnectionFactory.setUser("user");
        artemisConnectionFactory.setPassword("xxxxx");
        return artemisConnectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Initialise {@link JmsTemplate} as required
     */
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(artemisSSLConnectionFactory());

        //setting PuSubDomain to true configures JmsTemplate to work with topics instead of queues
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Initialise {@link DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory} as required
     */
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws JMSException {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(artemisSSLConnectionFactory());
        //setting PuSubDomain to true configures the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory to work with topics instead of queues
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

`artemis.roles-properties`:

```
amq = admin
users=user
guests=guest
```

`artemis-users.properties`:

```
admin = xxxxx
system=xxxxx
user=xxxxx
guest=xxxxx
```

`login.config`:

```
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";

    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.GuestLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.user="guest"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.role="guests";
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely a problem with your configuration. The error message even says so:

```
ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224018: Failed to create session: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
Line 11: expected [{], found [sufficient]
```

Given that it found the word `sufficient` when it was looking for `{` I conclude that the problem is in your `etc/login.config` since that's almost certainly the only place the word `sufficient` appears and because it's related to security.

The `login.config` you pasted looks fine to me so my guess is that you pasted the contents of a `login.config` that isn't actually being used by the broker.

Also, the `AMQ221053` message has been in the code-base since the 1.0 release. See [ARTEMIS-36](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-36).

Lastly, it's kind of odd for you to be specifying the keystore and truststore on both the client and the broker without also specifying `needClientAuth=true` or `wantClientAuth=true` on the broker. You would only specify a keystore on a client and a truststore on the broker if you wanted to do mutual SSL, but without `needClientAuth=true` or `wantClientAuth=true` that won't actually happen.

Comment: You're right. There was some additional text at the very bottom of the file, after the `};` in the `login.config` file. That probably came in when I was copying from another `login.config` file  Removing that text rectified the issue and I'm able to connect to the broker now. Additionally, I don't intend to do mutual SSL; I've got only the truststore on the Spring Boot client, no keystore. This setup gives me the one-way auth I need, should anything be changed there?

Comment: If you're *not* doing mutual SSL then the broker doesn't need a truststore (configured via `trustStorePath` & `trustStorePassword` on the `acceptor` in `broker.xml`) and the client doesn't need a keystore (e.g. `pathToKeystore` in your `MQTTConfig`). It would simplify your configuration/code to remove those unnecessary elements.

Comment: Got it, the `pathToKeystore` value was just being fetched from my `application.properties` file, I wasn't using it in the connection factory setup. I'll remove that and the `trustStore` related elements from the broker.